# Kubernetes - ClusterRole with namespace is allowed?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, roles, access-control, rbac

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) says,

> If you want to define a role within a namespace, use a `Role`; if you want to define a role cluster-wide, use a `ClusterRole`.

So, why am I able to create a `ClusterRole` in a namespace for a non-namespaced resource `StorageClass` (or, `sc` in short)?

```sh
kubectl -n apps create clusterrole scrole --verb=create,update,patch,delete --resource=sc
```

Also, is it correct to say that, a `Role` is applicable for namespaced resources *only* and `ClusterRole` for non-namespaced resources *only*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The namespace parameter is redundant and not used even if you provide it while creating a `ClusterRole`.

A `ClusterRole` can define permission to namespace scoped resources as well and you can use a `RoleBinding` to assign the permission to a user or group or service account. When you do that it's basically providing permission to the resources within the namespace where the `RoleBinding` is created.This is to avoid creating duplicate `Roles` in every namespace to provide the same permission.

Also when you have cluster scoped resources in a `ClusterRole` you need to use a `ClusterRoleBinding` to assign the permission to a a user or group or service account.